# ARToolKit-Recognize multiple markers

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

i'm having a problem with ARToolKit for the recognition of multiple markers.
For train pc on my new markers i have to launch :MK_PATT 
But when i insert the camera parameter filename ,i have this error message:

{
`Using supplied video config string [videotestsrc].
libARvideo: GStreamer 0.10.36

(mk_patt:2895): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `GstVideoTestSrc' to`GstBin'

(mk_patt:2895): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bin_get_by_name: assertion `GST_IS_BIN (bin)' failed
Pipeline has no element named 'artoolkit'!
setupCamera(): Unable to open connection to camera.
main(): Unable to set up AR camera.`
}

Answer (score 1):

Add

> identity name=artoolkit

To either your ARTOOLKIT_CONFIG var or your vconf variable depending on how you are handling it.